# basis for the unit sphere?

Tags: linear-algebra

This is a question from Pinter's *A Book of Abstract Algebra* p 289

He asks for a basis of the subspace of  $\mathbb{R}^3$ spanned by the set of vectors $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$

I don't really understand this questions but it seems like since the sphere is a surface it should be a basis with two elements that are linearly independent.

So can we just choose $(1,0,0),(0,1,0)$ as our basis? They are in the space and linearly independent but how would we ever write say $(\sqrt{(1/3)},\sqrt{(1/3)},\sqrt{(1/3)})$.

**Edit**: This is exercise **C.6** of Chapter 28 (Vector Spaces) of Pinter's book. The exact wording of the exercise is:

> Find a basis for the subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ spanned by the set of vectors $(x,y,z)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$.

Comment: $(\sqrt{(1/3)},\sqrt{(1/3)},\sqrt{(1/3)})=\sqrt{(1/3)}(1,0,0)+\sqrt{(1/3)}(0,1,0)+\sqrt{(1/3)}(0,0,1) $.

Comment: @Nikhil see you had to use all three basis elements though

Comment: What kind of basis are we talking about? Presumably not a linear basis, given that this isn't a linear subspace!

Comment: The $0$-vector is in any subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$. It is not on the sphere. Subspaces are, apart from the two trivial cases the $0$-vector and the whole space, lines and planes through the origin.

Comment: Ok I have edited the question to more directly reflect the wording in the book I must have misinterpreted the statement of the question.

Comment: @user9352 we cant express vectors with a non-zero z-component using only $(1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$, so all three vectors must be in the basis. By definition, basis is the set of linearly independent vectors such that all vectors in a vector space can be expressed as a linear combination of them. your set of 2 vectors doesnt satisfy this condition for $\mathbb{R^3}$, so it cant be a basis for $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Comment: So I think now that the vectors in question must span all of $R^3$ since the standard basis is included among them. So the standard basis will answer the question.

Comment: @user9352: Yes, "spanned" makes all the difference.  Space spanned is $\mathbb{R}^3$, since the standard basis vectors are on the sphere. So any basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$ will do, and there is nothing cheaper.

Comment: Please typeset in the question as it actually appears, including punctuation. What you typed is grammatically ambiguous at best.

Comment: Note that this exercise actually asks you to find an element in $GL(3)$. (set of 3x3-matrices with determinant $\pm 1$)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$ all satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and those three vectors span all of $\mathbb{R}^3$, the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ for which a basis is sought is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Thus, you need $3$ basis vectors, such as the three given above.

Comment: The set of vectors $x,y,z$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ are not closed under scalar multiplication, they don't form a subspace.

Comment: @hchar: we are not supposed to find a basis for the vectors $(x,y,z)$ that satisfy $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ (because they don't form a vector space). Those are the vectors from which we are choosing to get a basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.